# Using non-member function to extract class-objects from an input stream

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I had a go at overloaded operators with classes and here's what I did:

Firstly, vverloading the '<<' operator to insert objects of a class to ostream [Success]

```
class complex
{
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const complex &z);

    // codes that worked!
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const complex &z) {// conditions}
```

Then, I wanted to do the similar to '>>' operator, allowing the use of '>>' to extract objects of a class from istream. So I followed the documentation from MSDN:

```
// Inside the class declaration:
friend istream& operator>>(istream &is, const complex &z);

// Outside the class, before main function:
istream& operator>>(istream &is, const complex &z)
{
    is >> z.re >> z.im; // 're' and 'im' corresponds to real or imaginary numbers which are stored as doubles in each complex object
    return is;
}
```

While this has the same format as the example codes from MSDN, this resulted in compiling errors:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('istream'
  (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'double')
is >> z.re >> z.im;
```

Can someone help me comprehend the error message, or point out what I did wrong if you can tell the errors in my codes. Cheers.

Comment: The input operator would have to use a non-const reference to be able to update the parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MSDN didn't have a `const` on the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the problem and wrote a comprehensive solution to overloading the '>>' operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BoPersson and @molbdnilo pointed out in the comments, the input operator should use a non-const reference to update parameters. To update an object, we need to add two void functions under the public members of our class:

```
// The following codes are to be added inside the class
// Function to set the real part of a complex object
void setReal(double realPart){
    re = realPart;
}

// Function to set the imaginary part of a complex object
void setImg(double imaginaryPart){
    im = imaginaryPart;
}
```

Having put a 'friend' inside the class, the overloading function is declared outside the class:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &is, complex &z)
{
// Declare variables
double realPart, imaginaryPart;
// Extract real and imaginary parts from istream and save to above variables
is >> realPart >> imaginaryPart;
// Assign values to real and imaginary parts of a complex number in istream
z.setReal(realPart);
z.setImg(imaginaryPart);
return is;
}
```

Now we can extract complex (class) objects from istream in the main:

```
complex cNum;
cout << "Enter real and imaginary parts of a complex number: " << endl;
cin >> cNum;
```

The overloaded operator '<<' then can be used to print out chosen complex numbers.